# AWS instance type families - rule of thumb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Does anyone have a rule of thumb for selecting AWS instance families based on the purpose of the machine?

For example for database servers, go with xxx optimized, for web servers go with yyy optimized.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't know anything about the workload, I will generally start with compute optimized for web servers and memory optimized for db servers.

Within AWS, if you choose the wrong instance to start with, its easy to stop and switch it to another type.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to understand the failure mode of your application/service to answer this question.  How will your service fail under heavy load? Is it CPU bound, I/O bound, or memory bound?  You should pick an appropriate instance type to match the failure mode of your service.

If you are unsure of your failure mode, you might load test your service on different instance types to determine which instance types give you the most desirable performance characteristics for your service.